# Why Image not loading on android - xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

I put `crypto.png` image into drawable folder under Resources in Android Project.

After I right click on the image -> Build Action -> Embedded Resource.

In `MainPage.xaml` on the main project I try to load the image like that:

```
<Image x:Name="HeadImage"
           WidthRequest="100"
           HeightRequest="100"
           MinimumHeightRequest="100"
           MinimumWidthRequest="100"
           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
           HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
           Aspect="AspectFit"
           Source="crypto.png"/>
```

But the image not load.

I try a second method like this in the c# code:

```
var HeadImage = new Image { Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit };
HeadImage.Source = ImageSource.FromFile("crypto.png");
```

And this method not worked again..

[image: Build Action]

Comment: Can you give me example, I will accept your answer

Comment: I try with:  HeadImage = new Image { Source = ImageSource.FromResource("crypto.png") }; ant this not work again for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to let your image in `drawable` folder as `Android Resource` instead of `Embedded Resource`, and to use it, you need to:

```
HeadImage.Source = "crypto.png";
```

Also, before set the image, is a good practice to remove `MinimumWidthRequest and MinimumHeightRequest`. This is safe ONLY if you are sure the image have this minimum size. Otherwise, your image will not appear.

To know more about image in Xamarin, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#local-images).

And to understand the difference between the ways of set an `ImageSource` see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#embedded-images).